# Android - mysql php

Tags: java, android, mysql

**this program is to get a name from online mysql database by entering an id and sending request to php online file and the response is the name
what is wrong with the code ? I get no name**

**xml**

```
//activity_main.xml

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonGet"
                android:text="Get"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Main class**

```
//MainActivity.class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextId;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void getData() {
        String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = data.getString(Config.KEY_Name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getData();
    }
}
```

**Config class**

```
public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "myPhpURL";
    public static final String KEY_Name = "name";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting if you request is GET or POST, and you are not setting actual arguments for server. You are missing following piece of code

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("key", value);
        return parameters;
    }
```